# Grid layout has space on last column

Tags: android

I have set up a grid layout with 6 columns and there is a space between column 5 and 6. The grid contains image buttons all with the same size. I have tried to use fill_parent and wrap_content but the gap still shows. I have also tried layout gravity=1 without results.

button image dimensions 104 x 104 pixels
The device is Samsung tab A

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            tools:context=".Main">


<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:columnCount="6"

    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="MASTER 100"
        android:id="@+id/textView_master"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/masterup"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="@drawable/masterup"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/masterdn"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="@drawable/masterdn"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="117dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="100"
        android:id="@+id/tv_RGBAW_Value"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:textSize="100dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textColor="#0aff1f"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/blackout"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:background="@drawable/blackout"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="565dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Fixture"
        android:id="@+id/tv_fixture_data"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="6"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="#d8ffba"
        android:textColor="#120dff"
        />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="20px"
        android:layout_height="20px"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0"/>



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="100"
        android:id="@+id/textViewred"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#0fff33"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="100"
        android:id="@+id/textViewgreen"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#0fff33"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="100"
        android:id="@+id/textViewblue"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#0fff33"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="100"
        android:id="@+id/textViewamber"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#0fff33"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="100"
        android:id="@+id/textViewwhite"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#0fff33"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="SLOW"
        android:id="@+id/tv_speed"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/redup"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="@drawable/redup"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/greenup"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="@drawable/greenup"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/blueup"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:background="@drawable/blueup"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/amberup"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:background="@drawable/amberup"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/whiteup"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:background="@drawable/whiteup"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/speed"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:background="@drawable/speed"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="RED"
        android:id="@+id/red_active"
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#fdffff"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="GREEN"
        android:id="@+id/green_active"
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="BLUE"
        android:id="@+id/blue_Active"
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="AMBER"
        android:id="@+id/amber_active"
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="WHITE"
        android:id="@+id/white_active"
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/reddn"
        android:layout_row="9"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="@drawable/reddn"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/greendn"
        android:layout_row="9"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="@drawable/greendn"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bluedn"
        android:layout_row="9"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:background="@drawable/bluedn"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/amberdn"
        android:layout_row="9"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:background="@drawable/amberdn"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/whitedn"
        android:layout_row="9"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:background="@drawable/whitedn"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/full"
        android:layout_row="9"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:background="@drawable/full"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="FIXTURES"
        android:id="@+id/tv_fixturestatus"
        android:layout_row="10"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/q1"
        android:layout_row="11"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="@drawable/q1_buttons"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/q2"
        android:layout_row="11"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="@drawable/q2_buttons"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/q3"
        android:layout_row="11"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:background="@drawable/q3_buttons"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/q4"
        android:layout_row="11"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:background="@drawable/q4_buttons"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_row="11"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:background="@drawable/play_button"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/record"
        android:layout_row="11"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:background="@drawable/rec"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/q5"
        android:layout_row="12"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="@drawable/q5_buttons"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/q6"
        android:layout_row="12"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="@drawable/q6_buttons"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/q7"
        android:layout_row="12"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:background="@drawable/q7_buttons"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/q8"
        android:layout_row="12"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:background="@drawable/q8_buttons"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/group"
        android:layout_row="12"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:background="@drawable/go"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/all"
        android:layout_row="12"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:background="@drawable/all"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="COLOR ROLL"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_row="13"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cr1"
        android:layout_row="14"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="@drawable/rc1"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cr2"
        android:layout_row="14"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cr2"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cr3"
        android:layout_row="14"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:background="@drawable/cr3"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cr_stop"
        android:layout_row="14"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:background="@drawable/cr_stop"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/shift"
        android:layout_row="14"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:background="@drawable/shift"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="20px"
        android:layout_height="190px"
        android:layout_row="15"
        android:layout_column="0"/>

</GridLayout>
```

I use an button margin

```
<resources>
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="button_margin">5dp</dimen>
<dimen name="image_button_height">85dp</dimen>
<dimen name="image_button_width">85dp</dimen>
```

[image]

Comment: show a screenshot of the layout with the layout bound and clearly point out where the space is.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Link will not allow me to add photo. I will try again later.

Comment: Picture added. Any thoughts ?

Comment: You forgot to turn on LayoutBounds in the dev settings